# How to call angularjs function controller from jquery in asp.net webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, angularjs

i want to call angularjs function from jquery in a asp.net webpage its working in a normal html page but its not working asp.net webpage. Please help me am sctraching my head.

```
   angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.anyFunc = function (var1, var2) {
    alert("I am var1 = " + var1);
    alert("I am var2 = " + var2);
};
});

$(function(){

$("#hit").on("click",function(){

      angular.element($("#myctrl")).scope().anyFunc('VAR1 VALUE', 'VAR2 VALUE');

   });

 });
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">   </script>

   <div id="myctrl" ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 Call via jQuery
 <button id="hit">Call</button>
```

Comment: show your _"normal html"_ and _"asp.net webpage"_, what _not working_? Anyway it not good use function from angular scope outside

Comment: possibly you need use [ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) property